# Passing information between two forms from treeview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a sub that brings a second form with a treeview on it that is populated from an array. I want to click on an item on the array and pass the key and text back to the sub and close the second form.

I feel like this should be easy but I cannot figure this out. The array is passed to the treeview as follows.

```
    For j = 0 To NoFlowsheets - 1
        Form2.TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Flowsheet" & CStr(j), ColumnNames(j, 0))
        For k = 0 To j_max - 1
            If ColumnNames(j, k) <> "NAME_EMPTY DO_NOT_USE_THIS_NAME" Then
                Form2.TreeView1.Nodes(j).Nodes.Add("Flowsheet" & CStr(j), ColumnNames(j, k))
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    Form2.ShowDialog()
```

after this a form pops up with the treeview. I want the user to click on one of the items in the tree view and pass it back to the sub

Comment: please add more details to your question. it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Read all three parts of [this blog post](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).

Comment: Google "vb.net windows forms add your own event" to learn how to do it right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic example, but it shows how you can pass something into a form, and how to get back what the user selected/entered. You can easily modify this to pass in your array, and pass back the selected value(s).

On the first form (where you open the child form), you add code like this:

```
Public Class frmStart

    Private Sub btnAskUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAskUser.Click
        Dim frmAskUserAboutThemselves As New frmQuestion(19, "John Doe")
        frmAskUserAboutThemselves.ShowDialog(Me)
        If frmAskUserAboutThemselves.WasRecordSaved = True Then
            lblStatus.Text = "Name: " & frmAskUserAboutThemselves.ValueThatUserSelectedOnTheFormName & vbCrLf & "Age: " & frmAskUserAboutThemselves.ValueThatUserSelectedOnTheFormAge
        Else
            lblStatus.Text = "The user did not enter/select any values."
        End If
        frmAskUserAboutThemselves.Dispose()
        Beep()
    End Sub

End Class
```

On the child form (where you ask the user to select something), you add code like this:

```
Public Class frmQuestion

#Region " Override Windows Form Designer Generated Code "

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal iAge As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal sName As String = "")
        MyBase.New()

        m_iPassedInPersonAge = iAge
        m_sPassedInPersonName = sName

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Form Level Variables "

    Private m_iPassedInPersonAge As Integer = 0
    Private m_sPassedInPersonName As String = ""
    Private m_bWasRecordSaved As Boolean = False

#End Region

#Region " Form Level Functions "

    Public ReadOnly Property WasRecordSaved() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_bWasRecordSaved
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ValueThatUserSelectedOnTheFormName() As String
        Get
            Return m_sPassedInPersonName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ValueThatUserSelectedOnTheFormAge() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_iPassedInPersonAge
        End Get
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Normal Page Code "

    Private Sub frmQuestion_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtName.Text = m_sPassedInPersonName
        NumericUpDownAge.Value = m_iPassedInPersonAge
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        m_bWasRecordSaved = False
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        m_iPassedInPersonAge = NumericUpDownAge.Value
        m_sPassedInPersonName = txtName.Text.Trim
        m_bWasRecordSaved = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

If you are unsure what controls i placed on each form, just ask, but it should be pretty easy to figure that out.

Comment: I believe that this is the resolution to the issue, I am just trying to figure it all out, thanks for your help